# GridLayout (not GridView) : Items are not correctly positioned in GridLayout when trying to stretch them evenly

Tags: android, grid-layout

I'm trying to add 12 buttons to a 3X4 GridLayout with fixed width and height programmally.

All these buttons are supposed to stretch evenly inside the grid, but it doesn't work well in some cases when I adjust the width of the GridLayout.

It seems that the width has to be set **larger than a certain value** so that all the buttons can be positioned correctly.

Here is my code:

```
        gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
        gridLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        //width c 
        gridLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 300));
        gridLayout.setRowCount(NUM_OF_ROW);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(NUM_OF_COL);
        gridLayout.setUseDefaultMargins(false);
        for(int i = 0;i < NUM_OF_ROW; ++i){
            for(int j = 0;j < NUM_OF_COL; ++j){
                Button btn = new Button(this);

                gridLayout.addView(btn);

                GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();

                GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i,1,1);
                GridLayout.Spec colSpec = GridLayout.spec(j,1,1);
                params.rowSpec = rowSpec;
                params.columnSpec = colSpec;

                params.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);  
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        relativeLayout.addView(gridLayout);
```

Problem happens when width value set small enough.

[Output on a Samsung tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4CKg.png)
[Output I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nAkI.png)

Comment: show your output and how you want it to be

Comment: question has been updated, thank you